# I used URLRequest for images , but when publish , images were mixed up

Tags: android, image, actionscript-3, flash

i'm creating an android app using AS3 Adobe Flash, the app is like a library of images , having next and previous button, and images were already uploaded to a web page, so it's so simple.

So I've started coding by using URLRequest code to the frames by giving every frame this code:

```
var imageReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://im62.gulfup.com/coLnc.jpg');
var imageLoad:Loader = new Loader();

imageLoad.load(imageReq);

addChild(imageLoad);
```

and give the buttons the codes:
next frame , and previous frame

when I publish , the first image showed perfectly , but when I press next , the second image showed up to the previous image, and the same for the tiered frame , the image shows up to  the previous once and so ....etc  >__<

so what shall I do , please help if you can and thanks in advance ,
*here is the FLA file already attached
[these are the 3 images are shewn at the publish mode mixed up one up to the other](http://im90.gulfup.com/f13HL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Ahmed

Download this file:  [simple_picture_changer](http://www.umanoff.com/private/simple_picture_changer.zip)  unzip it and open the .fla.

Look at the script in frame 1. I've written comments there. That should get you started. If you have very many pictures, there are more elegant ways to script this, but this is still a good way to start to understand Actionscript3. There's lots of good documentation online.

Comment: that is just fantastic , it explains to me all what I was wondering...
don't know what to do to thank you for what you did ...
thanks thanks thanks i'm so glad

Comment: Mr Craig , it shows me this error when I publish it by Android Air :

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 39 1071: Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute Function, not nextpic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do all of this with code? You don't need a timeline.
Create a series of loaders, e.g. imageLoad1, imageLoad2, ...   Load your pictures. Put the loaders into an array.

Initially, you make the first image visible like this: `addChild(Arrayname[0])`

When you tap your 'next' button you'll say: `removeChild(Arrayname[0]; addChild(Arrayname[1];`inside a listener function, of course. Do you know how to set up listeners?

Comment: oh really glad that I got an answer :) thanks Craig 
so, I think I got what you mean ,,, that I shouldn't make lot's of actions at the frames , and make all actions at one frame by making imageLad1,imageLoad2, ...
i'll try to do this , but I'll be glad if you write me just one action example for one imageLoad, and the button action as an example , and I'll apply it to the others 
so many thanks Craig i'm so glad

Comment: I'll send you something in a little while.